# sql clustering - one db versus multipl dbs

Tags: sql, sql-server, cluster-computing

We're looking into setting up a SQL cluster for our app.

Our current setup is based on a very high number of small databases.

We are looking into setting up a cluster, but we are getting mixes opinions on whether to convert all our individual databases (about 5000) to one big individual database, or keeping our current setup.

Some say that it would be easier to manage one large database, and ensure high availability, while some say that managing a huge number of small databases would not be an issue. Any thoughts on this ?

We also want to make sure that should we scale and grow, and we get to 50000 databases, clustering etc. will still never cause issues.

Comment: So, is your question about clustering or combining databases?  They're separate strategies.

Comment: A bit of both I guess. I'd like to know if we should consider combining databases, if for ex this would help performance, etc. And also in a clustering environment, since this is what it looks like we need to go next, would having a high number of databases be problematic in the long run.

Comment: Why ask here, and not on the dba forum?

Comment: you've got a point, i'll post it on a dba forum as well. Meanwhile, if anyone has recommendations, I'd love hearing them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting into such large number of databases instinct tells me that you should look at design again ..and see if it make sense to have databases. Or should you consider logically dividing entities differently.  There is always admin overhead of too many dbs.  Also if you collapse into 1 db you might make it too big for backup /recovery etc..